# jquery not working to change inner html?

Tags: jquery

hey people I'm new at jquery and i have been trying to figure this out for like the past couple of hours... what the hell am I doing wrong here? All I want to do is change the innerHTML of a div.

```
$("left_menu_bar").innerHTML = "You clicked me!";
```

but the div doesn't change at all when I call the function with that code init.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
// referencing by id
$("#left_menu_bar").html("You clicked me!");
// referencing by class name ( will apply to all div's with this class )
$(".left_menu_bar").html("You clicked me!");
```

http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: `$("#left_menu_bar").html("you clicked me");`

Comment: Holy $%*# I didnt expect to get answers so fast i thought it would take a few days! thx!!!!

Answer (score 5):

jQuery always returns a jQuery *collection*--not a DOM element. In order to access DOM properties directly, you'll need to retrieve an element from the collection:

```
$(".left_menu_bar").first().innerHTML = "You clicked me!";
```

This isn't very convenient, however, and helmus's answer describes the way that things are usually done.

Answer (score 3):

You're attempting to assign some text to a property named `innerHTML` on an object that doesn't have a property named `innerHTML`.

The `$` function in jQuery doesn't return a DOM element. It returns a jQuery object which provides the ability to execute all the wonderful jQuery functions on set particular DOM elements.

One of the functions the jQuery object exposes is `.get()` which will return one of the elements it contains.

So in your case, you could do:

```
// 0 means it will return the first element in the jQuery object
$("left_menu_bar").get(0).innerHTML = "You clicked me!";
```

Or as @helmus stated in his answer, you could use the `.html()` function that jQuery provides to set the content which actually uses innerHTML on the inside.

Answer (score 2):

Since left_menu_bar isn't an element, you can't select it that way.

If it's the ID of an element, try:

```
$("#left_menu_bar").html("You clicked me!");
```

If it's the class of an element, try:

```
$(".left_menu_bar").html("You clicked me!");
```